# Styling of certain HTML elements

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, design

Definite low-priority [feature-request](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feature-request): when making notes and little *asides* in questions and answers, I tend to favour (ab)using `sub` and `sup`, both of which are visually precisely how I'd like them to be displayed on most other SE sites. So far only english.stackexchange.com doesn't quite conform to my desired styling of those elements in the same way.

Presently they both appear to be almost identical to the main body of text's style with only a slight decrease in text size, though not enough to make them as visibly different as they are on the other SE sites (you can *repro* this on Stack Overflow and Pro Webmasters).

To illustrate, this is how they're currently rendered on this site (YMMV in your browser):

<sup>This is a `sup` element</sup> (normal text for comparison)

<sub>This is a `sub` element</sub> (normal text for comparison)

This is how I'd like them to be rendered:

[image: Mock rendering of desired styling]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have increased the offsets slightly. The change will be in the next production build.